# Can not import table to MySQL database on linux

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, mariadb, cacti

I am trying to install cacti. When I want to import `mysql_test_data_timezone.sql` to MySQL database on Linux CentOS, I get an error.

My command is

```
mysql -u root -p mysql < /usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql
```

I get error

```
No such a file or directory ;
```

Does this directory have to exist or do I have to create it myself?

Comment: Is there some reason there is a `.` at the end of the filename? The command should be `mysql -u root -p mysql < /usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql`.

Comment: No .İ did not write '.'  .When I ask question ,I added it by mistake .

Answer (score 2):

Later versions of CentOS install mariadb-server in preference to mysql server. You can list the files installed by mariadb-server using the rpm utility

```
rpm -ql mariadb-server
```

you can then examine the output to see if the file you are looking for is installed (hint: it is, under a different path).

If you do not know which package (if any) provides a particular file you can use yum to search for it e.g.

```
yum provides /usr/share/mysql/mysql_test_data_timezone.sql
```

or to search more generally

```
yum provides */mysql_test_data_timezone.sql
```

Comment: Thank you a lot)  I provide particular file as you say and works